# Как прервать AsyncTask в его onPreExecute?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Имеется ли возможность прервать `AsyncTask` в его `onPreExecute()` (в зависимости от некоторого условия) и если да, насколько это оправдано в практическом применении?

Comment: Может быть подойдет `cancel(true);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А смысл? Не запускай AsyncTask в зависимости от некоторого условия.

Закрывать в  onPreExecute() - плохо. Получается что был создан лишний объект.

Если без этого никак не обойтись, используй решение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735102/ideal-way-to-cancel-an-executing-asynctask